# How to put subsection under section in headline in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, formatting, align, logos, headline

I want to put a subsection under the section in the headline in Beamer, but I also want to add the logo in the same line as a section. Section should be centered and logo on right side. I also want to subsection to disappear if that frame doesn't have subsection

Comment: Please add a minimal working example which will show us which theme etc. you use and include a sketch how the result should look like